# Query progressbar in sqlite and python

Tags: python, sqlite, progress-bar

I want to create a progressbar for queries, say i have a query that will take 40 seconds, i'd like to give some feedback to users on how long this will take and i found this code from oracle that is exactly matches what i want. Is there a same thing in sqlite?

```
from timemachine import oracle

guesser=oracle(guess="SQL")
guesser.set_hint(driver="pypgsql")
guesser.set_hint(gui="wx")

expected_runtime=guesser.estimate("<put your query text here>")
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the [`set_progress_handler()`](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.set_progress_handler) method of the [`sqlite3.Connection`](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#connection-objects) objects could be of use?